# Tune span parameter within stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

I would like to change the default *span* of the loess smoother when it is used within stat_summary.

```
stat_summary(fun.data ="mean_sdl",geom= 'smooth',se = TRUE ) #ugly result due to too small span
```

Is there an easy way to override the default 0.75 span parameter used in geom_smooth ?
Something like this :

```
stat_summary(fun.data ="mean_sdl",geom= 'smooth',se = TRUE,geom.span=2 )
```

Thanks !

Comment: `stat_summary(., fun.args = list(span = 2)`.

Comment: can you provide a bit more information about what you are trying to plot? If you want to plot the smooth and confidence interval, you don't need to call stat_summary

Comment: I would like to plot the residuals mean + standard deviation depending on another variable (typically time, to visualize a time-dependent residuals mean + standard deviation). I know there must be other ways to do it, using `geom_smooth` itself, but `stat_summary` would be easier if I could just tune the _span_ parameter.

Comment: @RuiBarradas `fun.args` refers to the `fun.data` function used to compute the statistics, not the smoother.

Comment: you are referring most likely to the standard error of the prediction, there's no way the stat_summary gives you anything related to residuals. My suggestion is to use geom_smooth(.. se=TRUE) , if it is more complicated than that, please elaborate in your question. Right now it's really vague

Comment: No, I am not referring to the standard error and I am not interested in how to compute residuals from `stat_summary`. It seems vague because you try to answer another question. My original problem is pretty simple : can we access the span parameter from the smoother within stat_summary ? yes or no